# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext') - after importing MUI components in react-redux environment

Tags: reactjs, node.js, material-ui

I have been debugging this for a while without success.

I have a really basic react-redux app like this

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';
import { Counter } from './features/counter/Counter';
import './App.css';

import Box from '@mui/material/Box';



import { NavBar } from './components/Navbar';

function App() {

  return (
    <>
    <div className="App">
        <Counter />
    </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

It renders correctly and you can even see I import a custom component.

However, whenever I import any MUI component like so:

```
return (
  <>
  <Box></Box>
  <div className="App">
    <Counter />
  </div>
  </>
);
```

I get an error like so:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
at useContext (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:63505:25)
at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:60374:66
at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:35774:22)
at updateForwardRef (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:38343:24)
at beginWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40390:20)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:25370:18)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:25414:20)
at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:25471:35)
at beginWork$1 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:45335:11)
at performUnitOfWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:44583:16)
```

Here is my folder structure:

[image]

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.4",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.15.4",
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^5.0.8",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "google-map-react": "^2.2.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.4",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.15.4",
    "react": "^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Maybe this will help: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73283925/17985195)

Comment: @TP95 I updated the post to include the folder structure. I believe this structure is correct but please let me know

Comment: I see package.json and package_lock.json in your parent folder, as per the link, see if deleting it helps (to be safe, instead of deleting just move them to a dump folder so that you can bring it back if it still does not fix it)

Comment: @TP95, I can try it but how would the app know what packages to install? This is the folder that contains the src folder which I believe is already the entire app folder

Comment: Its a demo app so it wouldn't hurt to try. Delete (or move) the package.json and package-lock.json files and run this command `npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled`

Comment: I deleted the files as well as the node modules folder and ran that command. It didn't seem to generate any new files.

I'm thinking this is a MUI compatibility issue with React 18? When I downgrade to React 17 I get a different set of errors complaining about hooks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256571/discussion-between-somethingstrang-and-tp95).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per discussions above and some guidance from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74322410/how-to-fix-cannot-read-properties-of-null-reading-usecontext/76438588#76438588), issue is resolved when deleting everything and re-creating the app with `create-react-app`.